# parquet format does not preserve the order of fields inside struct

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Used Spark sql to convert a json to Parquet format, something like this

```
Scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
Scala> val employee = sqlContext.read.json(“emplaoyee”)
Scala> employee.write.parquet(“employee.parquet”)
```

My employee json looks luke this
{"id":1,"name":"ABC","address":{"street":"s1","zipcode":123,"state":"KA"}}

I am trying to read the Parquet file using Amazon Athena. The table structure in Athena is like this
Create external table employee
{id string,
name string,
address struct

The problem is that order of the three fields inside address struct in the Parquet file is not preserved and thus I am not able to load it in the Athena schema defined as above.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would be interested to know if you have an answer. The problem in my case is the reading from the json not the writing to a parquet.